# Please clarify the W3C Label tag use

Tags: html

The W3C Specification for the label tag http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1 says:

> The LABEL element may be used to attach information to controls

Does "information" include error messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use it, as it is possible to attach more labels to a single input.

It also have accessibility considerations. [This article](http://www.punkchip.com/2010/12/aria-enhance-form-validation/) recommends the following (mind the `role` attribute):

```
<label for="userEmail" role="alert">That email address is invalid.</label>
```

Comment: Hmm. Where does the `role` attribute come from? It’s not in HTML. Do any screen readers recognise it? Does WAI-ARIA?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph It is defined by w3c's wai-aria: http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles